# Function wraps another function

Tags: c#, function

I have a set of static functions like

```
internal static List<ClassA> GetListOfClassA (int id, string name) {...}
internal static string GetName (int id) {...}
internal static List<ClassB> GetCompleteListOfClassB() {...}
```

What I would like to accomplish here is the following (written as pseudocode)

```
List<ClassA> newList = new List<ClassA>;
string newname;
List<ClassB> newListB = new List<ClassB>;

Pipe (newList = GetListOfClassA (5, "myname"));
Pipe (newname = GetName (5));
Pipe (newListB = GetCompleteListOfClassB());
```

Pipe should be a function that accepts another function with parameters, executes some code and allows to return the value of the function to the caller. Pipe should do something like

```
{
 Console.WriteLine ("Test");
 if (CertainCondition==true)
     return GetName (value);
 else 
    wait(250);
}
```

I tried all kind of things like lambda expressions or actions but I can't get it to work generically so that all kinds of functions are accepted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would work when you did it like this:

```
List<ClassA> newList = new List<ClassA>();
string newname;
List<ClassB> newListB = new List<ClassB>();

newList = Pipe(() => GetListOfClassA(5, "myname"));
newname = Pipe(() => GetName(5));
newListB = Pipe(() => GetCompleteListOfClassB());
```

You can implement `Pipe` like this:

```
public static T Pipe<T>(Func<T> action)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Entering pipe");
    if (someCondition)
        return action();
    else
    {
        // do something else; but you still need to return something
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

You could also implement it as a function that does not return anything on its own but requires an `Action` that has a side effect (e.g. setting a variable):

```
Pipe(() => newList = GetListOfClassA(5, "myname"));
Pipe(() => newname = GetName(5));
Pipe(() => newListB = GetCompleteListOfClassB());
```

The implementation would be very similar except that you do not need to return anything:

```
public static T Pipe<T>(Func<T> action)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Entering pipe");
    if (someCondition)
        action();
    else
        // do something else
}
```

The former has the benefit that there is a clear visibility of the side effect, i.e. the variable being set while the latter one leaves you in a situation where the variable could stay unassigned.

Comment: So, basically you would create a closure over the arguments and the actual invocation of the wrapped function is done on demand only? To put it differently, you would [curry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) away all of the arguments and leave conditional invocation to your generic function?

Comment: Yes, exactly! :) Of course you could also pass a reference to the function and all the arguments and then invoke the function dynamically within the implementation but that's not really worth the hassle. And lambdas are a lot more flexible here.

Answer (score 2):

My first guess is that Pipe does not pass any arguments to the 'GetName' function.

In that case you can let Pipe accept an `Action` and use it like

```
Pipe(() => newList = GetListOfClassA(5, "myname"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you would have to provide a generic version for every number of arguments for which you would like to evaluate as described. For the example with `GetListOfClassA`, which has 2 arguments and a return type, you could do it as follows.

```
public TResult Pipe<T1,T2,TResult>(Func<T1,T2,TResult> f, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
{
    Console.WriteLine ("Test");
    if (CertainCondition==true)
        return f(arg1, arg2);
    else 
        wait(250);
}
```

This function could be called as follows.

```
Pipe( GetListOfClassA, 5, "myname" );
```

You would have to provide similar versions for different number of arguments.